# symfony + api platform - creating alias to a route

Tags: php, symfony, routes, api-platform.com

We have a rather standard symfony + api-platform project.

A while ago, when a route was created it had a typo in it. I noticed that and want to fix it for the future. The problem is that some of our clients may have implemented it already like that. I want it to still work for a while, without being exposed in documentation. I can take care of the documentation part by overriding the generator service so that's not a problem.

The problem is that I find no way to create an alias in api-platform. Any idea how I may go about that? The item operations definition looks like this:

```
 *         get"={
 *             "method"="GET",
 *             "path"="/pathWithTypo/{id}",
 *             "requirements"={"id"="[0-9A-Z]+-[0-9A-Z]+"},
 *             "normalization_context"={"groups"={"someGroup"}}
 *         }
```

Comment: I would do it in webserver (apache, nginx) configuration, with a RewriteRule. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: Is not a bad idea. Although would've been great to add an alias as you do on controllers etc.

Comment: Have you tried to put the route in config/routes.yaml ? also with nelmio api doc you can filter out path you dont want to appear in the documentation (path_patterns).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just copy "get" operation and name it different:

```
itemOperations={
    "get"={
        "method"="GET",
        "path"="/pathWithTypo/{id}",
        "requirements"={"id"="[0-9A-Z]+-[0-9A-Z]+"},
        "normalization_context"={"groups"={"someGroup"}}
    },
    "get_without_typo"={
        "method"="GET",
        "path"="/pathWithoutTypo/{id}",
        "requirements"={"id"="[0-9A-Z]+-[0-9A-Z]+"},
        "normalization_context"={"groups"={"someGroup"}}
    }
```

So, then you can easily remove old `get` operation and rename `get_without_typo` to `get`.

To remove some endpoints from the documentation - I have created my own option - `remove_from_docs`. I can [share](https://gist.github.com/ERuban/b0b1264e3166e16ab173b9640584aed2) it with you.

Comment: I'll give it a shot.